# Improved IValueConverter -- MarkupExtension or DependencyObject?

Tags: c#, wpf, ivalueconverter, markup-extensions, dependencyobject

I saw online 2 different approaches to enhancing an IValueConverter. One of them extended a ValueConverter from MarkupExtension, the other from DependencyObject. I can't extend from both, so I'm wondering if any one is better than the other?

Comment: I guess it depends on what you're trying to achieve. Can you add some more details?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Deriving from each gives you different kind of power and flexibility:

- Deriving from `MarkupExtension` enables you to use the value converter without making it a static resource, as described below:

  ```
  public class DoubleMe : MarkupExtension, IValueConverter
  {
     public override object ProvideValue(IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
     {
        return this;
     }
     public object Convert(object value, /*rest of parameters*/ )
     {
        if ( value is int )
           return (int)(value) * 2; //double it
        else
           return value.ToString() + value.ToString();
     }
    //...
  }
  ```

  In XAML, you can directly use it without creating a StaticResource:

  ```
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name, Converter={local:DoubleMe}}"/>
  <TextBlock Text="{Binding Age, Converter={local:DoubleMe}}"/>
  ```

  Such code is very handy when debugging, as you can just write `local:DebugMe` and then can debug the DataContext of the control on which you use it.
- Deriving from `DependencyObject` enables you to *configure* the value converter with some preferences *in a more expressive way*, as described below:

  ```
  public class TruncateMe : DependencyObject, IValueConverter
  {
       public static readonly DependencyProperty MaxLengthProperty =
           DependencyProperty.Register("MaxLength",
                                        typeof(int),
                                        typeof(TruncateMe),
                                        new PropertyMetadata(100));
       public int MaxLength
       {
           get { return (int) this.GetValue(MaxLengthProperty); }
           set { this.SetValue(MaxLengthProperty, value); }
       }

       public object Convert(object value, /*rest of parameters*/ )
       {
          string s = value.ToString();
          if ( s.Length > MaxLength)
            return s.Substring(0, MaxLength) + "...";
        else
            return s;
       }
       //...
  }
  ```

  In XAML, you can directly use it as:

  ```
  <TextBlock>
     <TextBlock.Text>
         <Binding Path="FullDescription">
             <Binding.Converter>
               <local:TruncateMe MaxLength="50"/>
             </Binding.Converter>
         </Binding>
     </TextBlock.Text>
  ```

  What does it do? It truncates the string `FullDescription` if it is more than `50` characters!

@crazyarabian commented that:

> Your statement "Deriving from DependencyObject enables you to configure the value converter with some preferences in a more expressive way" isn't exclusive to DependencyObject as you can create the same MaxLength property on a MarkupExtension resulting in `<TextBlock Text="Binding Age, Converter={local:DoubleMe, MaxLength=50}}"/>`. I would argue that a MarkupExtension is more expressive and less verbose.

That is true. But then that is not bindable; that is, when you derive from `MarkupExtension`, then you cannot do :

```
MaxLength="{Binding TextLength}"
```

But if you derive your converter from `DependencyObject`, then you can do the above. In that sense, it is *more expressive* compared to `MarkupExtension`.

Note that the target property must be a `DependencyProperty` for `Binding` to work. [MSDN says,](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.binding.aspx)

> - Each binding typically has these four components: a binding target
>     object, a target property, a binding
>     source, and a Path to the value in the
>     binding source to use. For example, if
>     you want to bind the content of a
>     TextBox to the Name property of an
>     Employee object, your target object is
>     the TextBox, **the target property is
>     the Text property**, the value to use is
>     Name, and the source object is the
>     Employee object.
> - **The target property must be a dependency property.**

Comment: I saw Kent Boogaart's Converters project on Codeplex extending all the IValueConverter's he wrote from DependencyObject. http://wpfconverters.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/61942#

Comment: @Nawaz Your statement "Deriving from `DependencyObject` enables you to configure the value converter with some preferences in a more expressive way" isn't exclusive to `DependencyObject` as you can create the same `MaxLength` property on a `MarkupExtension` resulting in `<TextBlock Text="Binding Age, Converter={local:DoubleMe, MaxLength=50}}"/>`. I would argue that a `MarkupExtension` is more expressive and less verbose.

Comment: @crazyarabian: Yes. You can do that, But then that is not bindable. You cannot do `MaxLength="{Binding TextLength}"`.

Comment: @crazyarabian: Read the updated answer with more explanation.

Comment: @Nawaz: I was going to contribute my own answer illustrating that the only beneficial difference is that `DependencyObject` enables bindable properties (but I got sidetracked). While I like like and agree with the updates you've made, your code examples and initial answer still imply that `DependencyObject` allows for configuration with properties while `MarkupExtension` does not.

Comment: Actually, the reason I extended DependencyObject is because it allows you to use a virtual branch so that you can *bind properties of your converter*. The stated examples won't work because the converter is not part of the visual tree, be it defined as a resource or inline. Read about virtual branching here: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/AttachingVirtualBranches.aspx

Comment: @KentBoogaart: Care to throw in an answer to this? I love catching anything the WPF gurus throw their hat into...

Comment: @KentBoogaart @Nawaz, I'm trying to achieve the `DependencyObject` way in Silverlight without great success, am I missing anything?

Answer (score 5):

Since it's [my library](http://wpfconverters.codeplex.com) you're citing as an example of converters that extend `DependencyObject`, I think it fitting to explain myself.

I actually started out by simply implementing `IValueConverter` with `Object` as my base class. The only reason I switched to extending `DependencyObject` was to allow for a technique - pioneered by Josh Smith - called **virtual branching**. You can read about that technique [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/WPF/AttachingVirtualBranches.aspx).

Suppose you want to do something like this:

```
<UserControl.Resources>
    <con:CaseConverter Casing="{Binding SomeProperty}"/>
</UserControl.Resources>
```

This won't work because resources are not part of the visual tree, and so the binding will fail. Virtual branching hacks around this little dilemma, enabling you to perform such a binding. However, it still relies - like any other WPF binding - on the target being a `DependencyObject`. Thus, if I simply implemented `IValueConverter` without extending `DependencyObject`, you would be precluded from using virtual branches.

Now, if I'm completely honest, I'm not sure I'd still do this if I had my time again. I've never actually *had* to use a virtual branch myself - I just wanted to enable the scenario. I may even change this in a future version of my library. So my advice would be stick to a base class of `Object` (or a simple derivative thereof) unless you really think you'll need virtual branching.