# Use keys from one dotnet Maui resource dictionary file in another resource dictionary file

Tags: c#, xaml, maui, resourcedictionary

I have two resource dictionary files, Colors.xaml and Styles.xaml

I consume them from App.xaml like this

```
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Colors.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

I want nodes in Styles.xaml to be able to use keys from Colors.xaml

Such as this in Colors.xaml

```
  <Color x:Key="MySpecialColor">#0000FF</Color>
```

```
 <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource MySpecialColor}" />
```

The app compiles and I can even control+click in VS2022 from the usage of MySpecialColor in Styles.xaml and it goes to the correct place in Colors.xaml, but at runtime I get this error

```
[mono-rt]  ---> Microsoft.Maui.Controls.Xaml.XamlParseException: Position 25:58. StaticResource not found for key MySpecialColor
```

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21731970/2787772) from a relatively similar question about WPF not Maui, suggests using a DynamicResource instead of a static resource. This doesn't work for Maui, I get the same error. Plus even if it did, I would like to statically type it if I can.

Comment: If you move the style from styles.xaml to app.xaml, does DynamicResource work? If so, then either do that, or in app.xaml.cs, after InitializeComponent, copy the keyvalue pairs from style.xaml directly into app resources (doing so should be equivalent to defining it in app.xaml).

Answer (score 0):

First of all, did you check the default maui project template? There are two  resource dictionaries in the **/Resources/Styles** folder : Colors.xaml and Styles.xaml.

```
    <Application.Resources>
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Colors.xaml" />
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Resources/Styles/Styles.xaml" />
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </Application.Resources>
```

And the key in the `Colors.xaml` is used in the `Styles.xaml`. And I also tried to add a custom color in Colors.xaml:

```
  <Color x:Key="MyColor">#0000FF</Color>
```

And use it for the Button's style:

```
<Style TargetType="Button">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{StaticResource MyColor}" />
```

And the button's text color will be changed.

Comment: I guess my issue is something to do with my implementation then. I haven't been able to work it out. I know it's something to do with DI but haven't gotten to the bottom of it.

Comment: Did you check is there any other key in the Colors.xaml used in the Styles.xaml? @AdamDiament

Comment: Yes there are. But if I remove all references except one, the issue still occurs. Even if the staticresource is not even referenced in any of my xaml files

Comment: Can you provide a smallest sample which can reproduce your problem? @AdamDiament